# Событие на закрытие вкладки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите ,как реализовать защиту от случайного закрытия вкладки ? Я вкурсе про `window.onunload` и `window.onbeforeunload`, но они работают не всегда и некорректно. Например, в Opera они вовсе не воспринимаются. Нужно универсальное, которое работало бы везде. Можете что подсказать ?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными событиями выгрузки документа являются только `beforeunload` и `unload`.

Они работают всегда (при их поддержке браузером), но есть ограничения допустимых действий в обработчиках этих событий.
В частности, диалоги вызванные из обработчиков события `unload`  документа - не будут отображены.
Остальные ограничения, целиком и полностью **зависят от браузера** и его настроек. На эти вещи нельзя повлиять из JavaScript документа (иногда можно из расширения).

Отмена выгрузки документа возможна только в обработчике события `beforeunload` - опять же, лишь в том случае если браузер разрешит запрос пользователю:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Попытка отменить выгрузку стандартным способом 
  e.preventDefault();
  // Установка строки запроса пользователю
  e.returnValue = 'Вы уверены в том что хотите покинуть страницу?'; 
});
```

Браузер может проигнорировать строку в `returnValue`, показав свой текст, но присвоение этому свойству какого-либо строкового значения требуется для показа диалога (как минимум в Chrome).
"Тихая" отмена выгрузки, без диалога подтверждения - ни в одном браузере не поддерживается, насколько знаю. И это правильно.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, универсального решения нет.

`onbeforeunload` поддерживается в Opera на основе движка WebKit, но не работает в предыдущих версиях, основанных на Presto.

С точки зрения дизайна пользовательского интерфейса, я бы рекомендовал просто придерживаться `onunload`. И выполнять `ajax` в данном методе, чтобы сохранить состояние вашей страницы.

`onbeforeunload` не рекомендуется использовать, так как оно мало что делает, кроме как раздражает пользователя предупреждающим сообщением.

возможно, вам поможет данная статья

> https://www.zachleat.com/web/dont-let-the-door-hit-you-onunload-and-onbeforeunload/